# System calls from Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to use Shiny to build an app that allows users to load a CSV file, where it gets analyzed and a Create Table DDL is generated in Redshift.

To do this, I'm using csvkit's csvsql and I'm testing this on CentOS 6.5 and running R 3.2.1. http://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/scripts/csvsql.html

When I sudo su as the shiny user, and run

```
system('csvsql -i postgresql /srv/shiny-server/temp/tempcsv.csv >> /srv/shiny-server/temp/sql.sql')
```

it creates a sql.sql file with the create table DDL as expected.

However, when I run it in the web-app, like this, an empty sql.sql file is generated.

```
output$sql <- renderText({
system('echo test >> /srv/shiny-server/tablecreator/temp/test.txt')
system('csvsql -i postgresql /srv/shiny-server/temp/tempcsv.csv >> /srv/shiny-server/temp/sql.sql')
system('echo testtwo >> /srv/shiny-server/tablecreator/temp/test.txt')
print('finished')
})
```

I am able to see "test" and "testtwo" in the test.txt file, and also in the UI it renders "finished" properly.

I have also tried putting the system calls in their own .R file and using isolate with source and "local = TRUE", but it still generates an empty output.

This seems to indicate to me that the system call is not working as expected, but I don't really know how to debug this aside from sudo'ing in as shiny and testing the command (which works).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seem to have got this working by using stdin instead of the file location..

    system("cat '/srv/shiny-server/temp/tempcsv.csv' | csvsql -i postgresql > /srv/shiny-server/tablecreator/temp/sql.sql")

still not sure why this worked!